# Is there a way to set an ansible callback for a single task?

Tags: ansible

I'd like to set the `stdout_callback` for a single task. This doesn't work:

```
tasks:
  - command: "echo abc; echo def; echo ghi"
    stdout_callback: debug
```

Comment: I really doubt there is any way to do that.

Comment: It's not possible. Maybe there is a solution If you describe the use-case.

Comment: I want to format the output of one task in a way that’s human readable, that’s all. The defaults in Ansible are atrocious, and the UX sadly sucks :/ I know how to do it using a custom module, but I hope there’s a standard way to do what one would think should be a normal behavior.

Comment: Use case.  For most things the normal compact output of ansible is just fine!
But when the play determines something is bad and it is going to abort, then having it output the actual reason in a human readable form make it a lot easier to then triage.   Being able to switch in such conditions would be much more useful!  Say for 'debug' and 'assert' task messages.  The JSON can still be output for logs, but human readable for the stop condition is more useful.